# Android apk analysis to determine SMS destination

Tags: android, apk, smsmanager

I have a set of approximately 200 Android apk files that have been flagged by a system as suspicious because of their use of the SEND_SMS permission. What, if any, static/dynamic analysis techniques can I perform on these apk files to determine the destination for SMSs sent by each application? I'm trying to determine if they send premium rate or regular SMS.

I've thought of naively pulling strings from the apk files and parsing out phone numbers. Is there a more systematic way to go about this?

Comment: use dex2jar / jd or similar to get the java ocde and then search for the calls to the sms API

Comment: Yes that can work (but may involve tracing variables), but I wanted something that doesn't involve manual analysis, since that does not scale well. I was hoping for some sort of instrumented Android emulator that could statically/dynamically perform the required task.

Comment: Make a script with apktool to get the source code of the app and parse each file with a regex that match phone numbers.